# Como abrir um arquivo PHP no navegador?

Tags: php

Estou tentando abrir arquivos com a extensão `.php`.

- No Firefox, ele pede para realizar o download.
- No `IE` ele pede para realizar o download.
- Já no `Chrome` ele exibe o código PHP.

Antes não estava assim, ficou assim por estes tempos. Como eu posso abrir os arquivos em PHP no meu navegador?

Comment: Você precisa usar um servidor web (mesmo que local) para servir o arquivo. Se acessar com `file:///`, o resultado é esse.

Comment: @bfavaretto não me parece que seja esse o problema.

Comment: Pois bem, assim eu acessava creio eu, HTML roda sem problemas, PHP não roda, entendo que para funcionar por completo precisa estar em um servidor, mesmo que local, mas ao menos era para ser exibido o documento mesmo que vazio, ao invés de solicitar download..
Os arquivos HTML são abertos assim: 
`file:///C:/testes/meuarquivo.html`
Phps também:
`file:///C:/testes/meuarquivo.php`

Comment: Mas o PHP nunca vai ser interpretado se não rodar em um servidor. Com `file:///`, se o browser vai mostrar o código-fonte ou forçar um download é decisão dele (talvez seja até configurável, mas não sei ao certo).

Comment: Firefox, Chrome, IE, nenhum gosta de exibir meu documento PHP, alias, no Chrome ele exibe o código do documento, o que já soa como estranho.
Tenho um servidor WAMP, para exibir os arquivos PHP, e pede para download. Mas independente disso, sem ou com servidor, eu já acessava PHP no firefox para estruturar o HTML sem ter estes problemas.

Comment: No sense... o Navegador apenas interpreta as tags HTML e "desenha" o seu arquivo, .php por definição é um arquivo que necessita de um interpretador PHP independentemente de possuir tags HTML ou não.....

Comment: Bom, aqui funcionou o PHP acessando pelo endereço do servidor wamp, e não o local onde o arquivo fica.
Estava acessando com file:/.... e agora está indo por localhost/, sem solicitar download ou coisa do tipo.
Mesmo assim, fico com um misterio na minha cabeça.. Eu abria PHP antes, a 10 dias atrás, direto no navegador, pelo endereço file... e abria normalmente, PHP não era executado, mas o HTML era lido e a página era exibida.
Isso que me soa como estranho!... Agradeço a todos, e se alguém tiver algo a dizer sobre isso, estou curioso.

Comment: Sobre seu último comentário, pode ter sido uma atualização do browser que mudou o comportamento.

Comment: @AlexandreC.Caus, o melhor que você tem a fazer é mostrar o seu código aqui. Assim, poderemos testar em nossos navegadores e analisar mais a fundo erro.

Comment: Pode ser apenas uma variação nas tags das páginas que você testou antes. Tem coisa que aparece, tem coisa que não. O resultado vai ser aleatório mesmo, pois um PHP não processado vai se comportar como um HTML quebrado, então vai depender de como os browsers tratam as exceções. O melhor é visualizar o código fonte pelos navegadores, em vez de tentar ver renderizado.

Comment: Eu já tive esse problema também. É estranho, mas o Firefox simplesmente pedia pra baixar o PHP toda vez que eu ia abrir a página no localhost

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### O PHP é uma linguagem de ***scripts* interpretada do lado do servidor**.

Não é como HTML que é uma linguagem de marcação de hipertexto, que irá rodar simplesmente ao abrir o arquivo.

A partir do momento que o interpretador PHP começa a agir, todo o código inserido dentro do documento começa a ser processado. Esse processamento gera um arquivo HTML e nesse arquivo vai existir somente *tags* HTML ou qualquer outra tecnologia *client-side*, que será retornado para quem solicitou o arquivo.

---

Para você conseguir fazer rodar arquivos com extensão `.php`, é necessário que tenha um [servidor web Apache](https://www.apache.org/) para transformar o computador em um servidor que irá interpretar os *scripts* PHP, e não exibir os códigos na tela.

Apesar de ser possível baixar os "componentes" (Banco de Dados, Apache, PHP) individualmente, é necessário um conhecimento razoável para configurá-los, já que pode ser <strike>extremamente</strike> complicado configurá-los na primeira vez.

Entretanto, existem algumas alternativas (programas) prontos, preparados com uma configuração padrão, que já vem com o que você precisa, que na maioria das vezes é a linguagem PHP, o banco de dados MySQL, e o servidor Apache.

Esses programas são conhecidos como:

- WAMP's (**W**indows, **A**pache, **M**ySQL, **P**HP),
- LAMP's (**L**inux, **A**pache, **M**ySQL, **P**HP) e
- MAMP's (**M**ac, **A**pache, **M**ySQL, **P**HP)

Você pode ver mais informações desses [programas aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info).

### Seu problema

Após ter lido esta introdução e estar com os programas instalados da sua escolha, quando você inicia o Windows, é necessário "*start*ar" o servidor (no meu caso o WAMP).

Você clica no ícone dele (na área de trabalho, ou no menu iniciar, ou no diretório de instalação) e quando ele ficar "verdinho", você pode abrir uma nova guia do seu navegador e digitar na barra de endereço (caso sua configuração seja a padrão) *localhost* ou *127.0.0.1*.

**Importante:** É necessário que você mova os arquivos (do seu projeto) para a pasta dentro do seu programa servidor web (se você está utilizando um dos programas citados acima), como o XAMPP - na pasta *htdocs* - ou WAMP - na pasta *www* - ou crie um *[`alias`](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/smb-technologist/create-aliases-on-your-wamp-server/)<sup>en</sup>.*

**Lembre-se**, PHP é uma linguagem de *scripts* interpretada do lado do servidor, então abrir os arquivos como HTML:

> `file:///C:/testes/meuarquivo.php`

Irá resultar em seu código sendo mostrado na tela ao invés de ser interpretado, independente de qual seja seu navegador. Então você deve abrir ele com o protocolo do servidor, algo como:

> `http://localhost/testes/meuarquivo.php`

**Outra coisa importante** que esqueci de mencionar: Caso esteja ocorrendo algum problema de, por exemplo, abrir alguma página inesperada, ou não abrir nada, é porque (provavelmente) você possui algum programa que está utilizando a porta 80 (padrão).

Programas instalados como Skype, ou IIS (que geralmente está instalado na maioria das máquinas de desenvolvimento) podem ocasionar isso. Então é necessário que você mude a porta do servidor.

Você pode ver mais informações relacionadas no site oficial (no meu caso [Wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)<sup>en</sup>), ou mais informações [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10366410).

Vou deixar aqui uma breve solução, caso você esteja utilizando WAMP:

- Clique no ícone do servidor WAMP> Apache> httpd.conf, depois altere a linha Listen 80 para Listen 8080 ou qualquer porta que você deseja.

  - Se você não conseguir acessar através do ícone, acesse no diretório em C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.23\conf> httpd.conf e faça o que foi dito acima.

Pode assistir [este vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dLmPzzP6n4w) também, que foi indicado na resposta que foi linkada acima, respondida no nosso [Grande Irmão SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083979/wamp-server-doesnt-load-localhost/).